# Error named " TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor"

Tags: python, pytorch

I am working on CNN code using PyTorch and my code is as follows:

```
import time
start_time=time.time()

epochs=10
train_losses=[]
test_losses=[]
train_correct=[]
test_correct=[]

for i in range(epochs):
    tsn_corr=[]
    tst_corr=[]
    
    for b, (X_train,y_train) in enumerate(train_loader):
        b+=1
        
        y_pred=model(X_train)
        loss=criterion(y_pred,y_train)
        
        #Tally the number of correct predictions
        
        predicted= torch.max(y_pred.data, 1)[1]
        batch_corr=(predicted==y_train).sum()
        tsn_corr += batch_corr
        
        #optimize paramters
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        #print interim results
        if b%600 == 0:
            print(f"epochs: {epochs}, batch: {b}, loss: {loss.item():10.8f}")
        
    loss=loss.detach().numpy()
    train_losses.append(loss)
    train_correct.append(tsn_corr)
```

When I run this code I am getting this error `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor`

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-42-72616e5c4066> in <module> 22 predicted= torch.max(y_pred.data, 1)[1] 23 batch_corr=(predicted==y_train).sum() ---> 24 tsn_corr += batch_corr 25 26 #optimize paramters – 
Ali Mashoud
Aug 14 at 15:22  
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in iter__(self) 583 return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__iter, (self,), self) 584 if self.dim() == 0: --> 585 raise TypeError('iteration over a 0-d tensor') 586 if torch._C._get_tracing_state(): 587 warnings.warn('Iterating over a tensor might cause the trace to be incorrect. ' TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor.
```

Can somebody explain me what I am doing wrong and what is the problem with the code.

Comment: What  is the complete error trace? How is `train_loader` defined?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean like?? The whole error line is this typeerror: iteration over a 0-d tensor

Comment: The train_loader is this:  train_loader=DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=10,shuffle=True)

Comment: I meant the whole entire error *error stack trace*... which is multiple lines long.

Comment: Oh!!! it is this:

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-72616e5c4066> in <module>
     22         predicted= torch.max(y_pred.data, 1)[1]
     23         batch_corr=(predicted==y_train).sum()
---> 24         tsn_corr += batch_corr
     25 
     26         #optimize paramters

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in __iter__(self)
    583             return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__iter__, (self,), self)
    584         if self.dim() == 0:
--> 585             raise TypeError('iteration over a 0-d tensor')
    586         if torch._C._get_tracing_state():
    587             warnings.warn('Iterating over a tensor might cause the trace to be incorrect. '

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor

Comment: Ok, could you also give the shape of `y_pred`?

Comment: torch.Size([10, 10])

Comment: y_pred.shape is like this which I commented in previous comment

Comment: The issue seems to step from the line with `batch_corr`, are you sure `predicted` and `y_train` have the correct shapes?

Comment: Yes I am following a notebook right now and the code is same as it is written here

Comment: do I need to run the test batches here as well

Comment: what could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: What is the output of `predicted==y_train`? Also, when someone asks for the complete stacktrace, please update your question instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have done this. I have added the complete trace.